# PHP - Compare multiple date-time's with +60sec

Tags: php, wordpress

Obviously I'm missing something, but can't figure out how to compare strings which are date&time but both got in different ways.

Code:

```
$mod_datetime =  get_the_modified_date() .' '.get_the_modified_time();
$curr_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i');
$plus_datetime = strtotime($mod_datetime) <= 0*0*0*60;
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');

if( ($curr_datetime < strtotime($mod_datetime)) > $plus_datetime){ 
    echo 'True';
} elseif ( 0*0*0*60 < (time() < strtotime($mod_datetime)) )  {
    echo 'Recently false';
} else {
    echo 'False at all';
}
}
```

In wordpress to get post last modification date and time - has to use $mod_datetime which gives me return like: 2021-05-09 15:21. String $curr_datetime returns me in same format, like: 2021-05-09 15:21 (it's all good with getting last modification date and current date.

But trouble is I'm getting wrong result in echo and obviously my if statement is in wrong way written. How to compare like:

if post has been edited 60 or less seconds ago - return true, otherwise - return false and goodbye, have a nice day.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: First off, combining comparisons like you do into an expression `(a < b) > c` doesn't make sense. The result of a comparison is a boolean value, so you end comparing `true` or `false` to a date string. If you want to check two conditions, you'll have to check them separately and join them with `&&`. Secondly, `0*0*0*60` equals `0`, not sure what you expected that to achieve. My final recommendation is to turn all your dates into `DateTime` objects and then compare them directly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Well probably my question wasn't clean enough. I just need to make if statement which checks - if action happened 60 sec. ago - set value yes, when 60sec. ago pass - value no

Comment: I understood what you were trying to do. I just pointed out all the things you used that don't make sense in that context. You're not actually comparing times in your code at all. You're comparing some date strings with some booleans and some zeroes. I think you need to revisit a tutorial about comparison.

Comment: Already did that, solved my problems and everything working good. Thanks for your time! Appreciate